# how to pass arguments to screen class

Tags: python-3.x, class, kivy

what is the equivalent to this

```
def name(first):
    print(first)

name(first = "hello")
```

in a class format?

I am working on a script where `kivy screen(s)` are created within a loop. Since the screens aren't hard coded, and called from the same class, they end up all being the same screen.

what I have is

```
class Account(Screen):
    coord = somedict["account_1"]["coordinate_x"]

for i in range(2):
    screenmanager.add_widget(Account())
```

what I want to be able to do is,

```
class Account(Screen, acc):
    coord = somedict[acc]["coordinate_x"]

for i in range(2):
    screenmanager.add_widget(Account(acc=str(i)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

1. Define a Kivy Property e.g. StringProperty at class level.
2. Add a constructor to receive the argument and assign it to that instance attribute.

### Snippets

```
class Account(Screen):
    coord = StringProperty('')

    def __init__(self, acc, **kwargs)
        super(Account, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.coord = somedict[acc]["coordinate_x"]

...

for i in range(2):
    screenmanager.add_widget(Account(acc=str(i)))
```

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from morsecode import morse

# Create both screens. Please note the root.manager.current: this is how
# you can control the ScreenManager from kv. Each screen has by default a
# property manager that gives you the instance of the ScreenManager used.
Builder.load_string("""
#:import choice random.choice
<MorseCode>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: root.code
        Button:
            text: 'Random Morsecode'
            on_release:
                root.manager.current = choice(root.manager.screen_names)
""")


class MorseCode(Screen):
    code = StringProperty('')

    def __init__(self, acc, **kwargs):
        super(MorseCode, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.code = morse[acc]


# Create the screen manager
sm = ScreenManager()

for i in range(1, 9):
    sm.add_widget(MorseCode(str(i), name='morsecode'+str(i)))


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

## Output

[image: Kivy ScreenManager]

Answer (score 0):

That seems quite basic stuff when using a class, typically done inside the  [`__init__`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__) method. There's plenty of examples out there of how this works, so I don't think it's really useful to explain that in more detail here.

Here's a snippet that should do for your case:

```
class Account(Screen):
    def __init__(self, acc):        
        self.coord = somedict[acc]["coordinate_x"]
```

Mainly the idea is not to make `coord` a class property but an instance property assigned during initialization of the instance, which can thereby be individual for each instance of the same class.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have tried this, the problem is, I cant seem to refer to the instance property in my .kv file. for example, without the __init__ function, if i wanted to set text equal to `coord` on my .kv file, i would do `text: root.coord` but when assigning `coord` under init, i get an attribute error.

Comment: a better question would be, how can I use the `acc` property outside of the __init__ function?